# VB 2010 Express: Data Type Variant from VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba

I am writting a library using VB 2010 Express to be called from VBA. I need to pass a variable of Variant type, which is an array containing several variable data type (double, integer and string), into a library function created by VB 2010 Express, and then pass out the results back to VBA. I am quite new to VB 2010 Express, and I find that data type Variant is not available in VB 2010 Express.

If I really want to pass data of variable data types into the library, rather than breaking the variable of Variant type into several variables of different data types, are there alternative ways to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: To get this straight, 1. you want to save few variable with other data types e.g. `i Int, l Long, str String, obj Object, var Variant...` into a `variant array`? 2. Then you want to access it from Excel ? 3. or do you want to parse it from Excel to .Net?

Comment: Thanks bonCodigo, I wan to pass it from Excel VBA to VB.Net